# Sprinkler system zone gets stuck on

Tags: sprinkler-system

While testing my sprinkler system (rain bird) one of my zones would not shut off and I had to turn the water off to get it to stop. I turned on that zone manually via the solenoid and the container where the solenoid is started filling up with water. The zone shut off when I turned off the knob that you use to manually turn it on (at the solenoid). This leads me to assume that the solenoid is bad and needs to be replaced.

One other thing that threw me off is right beside where my water meter is I have this box pictured below. It doesn't seem to do anything but have two shutoff valves to the sprinkler system.  The two blue handles shut off the water but I am not sure what the stuff in between does. The reason I mention this is this box also filled up completely with water.  If I trace the sprinkler lines there are two solenoid boxes before the one with the issue and those were both dry so there doesn't seem to be leaks elsewhere.

My questions are:

1) Is the solenoid likely the issue with the water staying on and should I replace that?

2) Is the box pictured below doing anything except providing a cutoff from the water line to the sprinkler system (so I can shut off the sprinkler w/o shutting off my water)?

3) Does the bad solenoid causing the sprinkler zone to stay on explain why the box below filled up with water?

[image: Sprinkler box]

Comment: What is pictured is a backflow preventer.  All the test ports appear to be closed. Can you tell specifically where the water filling that area was coming from?  I think you probably have a drain valve still open, or a broken pipe. It shouldn’t fill with water.

Comment: I couldn't tell but after it dries out I could check again and see if I could figure it out. Where would the drain valve be?